# check if filenames in a text file with filepaths is unique in the text file using bash

Tags: linux, bash, unix, awk

I have a text file supplied.tsv with filepaths and a column with filesize as follows, I want to ensure that the filenames are unique

```
./statistics/variant_calls/v12_HG03486_hgsvc_pbsq2-ccs_1000.snv.QUAL10.GQ100.vcf.cluster.stats  676
./statistics/variant_calls/v12_HG03486_hgsvc_pbsq2-ccs_1000.snv.QUAL10.GQ100.vcf.stats  788
./v12_config_20200721-092246_HG02818_HG03125_HG03486.json  887
./v12_config_20200721-092246_HG02818_HG03125_HG03486.json  887
./variant_calls/v12_HG02818_hgsvc_pbsq2-ccs_1000.wh-phased.vcf.bgz  566
./variant_calls/v12_HG02818_hgsvc_pbsq2-ccs_1000.wh-phased.vcf.bgz  566
./variant_calls/v12_HG02818_hgsvc_pbsq2-ccs_1000.wh-phased.vcf.bgz.tbi  772
```

Expected output
Yes all unique filenames

**MY PLAN**
I will extract the first column from file

```
awk -F"\t" '{print $1}' supplied.tsv > supplied_firstcolumn.txt
```

Extract filename and then check the distinct lines. Kindly let me know how to do this efficiently.

Comment: Pipe to `sort | uniq -d`. This will show all the duplicate names.

Comment: or use `awk '!seen[$1]++' file`

Comment: Expected output just "Yes"? You don't want any output if there is a duplicate in the input, not even the name of the duplicate string and/or the line number it occurs on?

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{ fil[$1]++ } END { for (i in fil) { if (fil[i]>1) { print i" - "fil[i];dup++ } } if (dup < 1) { print "No duplicates" } }' files.txt
```

Create an array called fil with the filename as the index and increment the value every time the file is seen. At the end, loop through the fil array and if the value is greater than 1, print the filename and the count. Also increment a duplicates count (dup). If the dup variable is less that 1 at the end of the loop, print "No duplicates"

Answer (score 0):

*how to do this efficiently*

As you are interested in *if*, not *how many* duplicates you have I suggest stop processing after hitting 1st duplicate. I would do it following way. Let `file.txt` content be:

```
./statistics/variant_calls/v12_HG03486_hgsvc_pbsq2-ccs_1000.snv.QUAL10.GQ100.vcf.cluster.stats  676
./statistics/variant_calls/v12_HG03486_hgsvc_pbsq2-ccs_1000.snv.QUAL10.GQ100.vcf.stats  788
./v12_config_20200721-092246_HG02818_HG03125_HG03486.json  887
./v12_config_20200721-092246_HG02818_HG03125_HG03486.json  887
./variant_calls/v12_HG02818_hgsvc_pbsq2-ccs_1000.wh-phased.vcf.bgz  566
./variant_calls/v12_HG02818_hgsvc_pbsq2-ccs_1000.wh-phased.vcf.bgz  566
./variant_calls/v12_HG02818_hgsvc_pbsq2-ccs_1000.wh-phased.vcf.bgz.tbi  772
```

then

```
awk 'BEGIN{uniq=1}(++arr[$1]>=2){uniq=0;exit}END{print uniq ? "all unique" : "found nonunique"}' file.txt
```

output

```
found nonunique
```

Explanation: Firstly I set `uniq` to `1`, which will stay such if not duplicates are found. Then for every line I increase counter in `arr` for given path (`$1`) and check if *after* that operation it is bigger or equal 2 - if it is this mean it is 2nd or following occurence, so I set `uniq` to `0` and end processing file using [exit](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Exit-Statement.html) - or in other words jump to `END`. In `END` I `print` pending on `uniq` value, if you prefer to print only if duplicate were not found, you might use `if(uniq){print "unique"}` in `END`.

*(tested in gawk 4.2.1)*